# Using Facebook Graph API Explorer to publish an action

Tags: facebook-graph-api

---

### Background

I'm creating a simple Facebook application, first time working with Facebook.
* Using an "Action Type" of "Read"
* Using an "Object Type" of "Article"

I can't submit the application because the Action Type shows an error "You, or this app's Open Graph Test User, must have published this action at least once."

---

### Immediate question:

I'm trying to publish the Action using the Graph API Explorer so that I can then submit the app for review.

I tried a GET /me/news.reads which didn't generate an error but only returned a blank results {"data":[]}
Also when I go back to look at the Action Type, it still shows the same error about needing to publish.

I tried the same request as a POST which did give an error "The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. At least one of the following properties must be specified: article."

On another notes, a more generic GET request I tried /me?fields=posts,feed gets me the data I want in the Graph API Explorer, but what would I set as my Action Type and Object Type to use that request?

Any comments on the overall approach I'm using would also be welcome.

---

More background: The underlying goal of this is that we want our separate corporate website to pull in the latest post to the Wall on our Page.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: _“The underlying goal of this is that we want our separate corporate website to pull in the latest post to the Wall on our Page.”_ – how would that require the use of Open Graph actions at all …?

Comment: When we post to Facebook, we want that post to also show up on our corporate website. 

I just completed the same task with Twitter, such that the latest Tweet also gets pulled to the corp website. In the Twitter admin pages I set up an "application" and got credentials and then on our site used PHP to contact Twitter and fetch the Tweet.

I read in a couple forums that Facebook was like that as well, that I should set up a Facebook application, get credentials, and then on the corporate website use PHP to pull the post in.

Not to be deliberately dense, but how should I achieve that goal?

Comment: Yeah, that has nothing to do with Open Graph actions at all. You can read a [page’s posts via a simple API call](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/). The [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) is a useful tool to play around with API requests and see what you get. To finally implement those requests into your page, it is recommendable to use the PHP SDK.

Comment: Thanks for responding.

* Even though a Page is public, it seems like the feed is private and requires oauth.
I made a test Page, made it public.
https://graph.facebook.com/rednoodlellc/

But the feed returns an oauth error
https://graph.facebook.com/rednoodlellc/feed

* I have the PHP SDK installed, but the config section wants an appID and secret.
  require_once("facebookSDK/facebook.php");
  $config = array(
      'appId' => '',
      'secret' => '',
      'fileUpload' => false, // optional
      'allowSignedRequest' => false, // optional, but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
  );

Comment: Of course the SDK wants an app id and secret – so go create an app.

Comment: But that brings me back to my original question. I did create an app, but can't submit it to Facebook for approval.

I can't submit it because my "Action Type" hasn't been published, and I can't figure out how to publish it.

The Object Type was Article and the Action Type was Read.

I read that you can use the Graph API Explorer to publish Actions, but nothing I've tried has worked.

Comment: You don’t need to submit your application for review if it is not using Open Graph actions …

Comment: When I delete the Action Type and object Type, The Submit and Review page says "There are no items included in this submission" by the "Submit for Review" button (which is grayed out). Thanks again.

Comment: As I said, you don’t _need_ to submit your app for review to just read a page’s feed. (Not sure from your last comment it that was clear now or not.)

Comment: It's working now, my PHP page got content. That I didn't need to submit for approval ultimately was what confused me. Many many thanks.